# Вывод в OpenMP C++

Tags: c++, openmp

Только начал знакомиться с OpenMP. Ниже простой код, вопрос по выводу. По сути должно выводить числа 1, 2, 3, 4. В консоли я получаю не особо понятные значения. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int count, ItsMe;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        count = omp_get_thread_num();
        ItsMe = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("Hello, OpenMP! I am %d of %d\n", count, ItsMe);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Результат в консоли:

```
sergey@sergey-H310M-S2H:~/Рабочий стол$ ./a.out
Hello, OpenMP! I am 2 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 3 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 0 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 2 of 4
sergey@sergey-H310M-S2H:~/Рабочий стол$ ./a.out
Hello, OpenMP! I am 1 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 0 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 3 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 2 of 4
sergey@sergey-H310M-S2H:~/Рабочий стол$ ./a.out
Hello, OpenMP! I am 0 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 1 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 3 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 2 of 4
sergey@sergey-H310M-S2H:~/Рабочий стол$ ./a.out
Hello, OpenMP! I am 0 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 3 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 2 of 4
Hello, OpenMP! I am 2 of 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта программа содержит неопределенное поведение, из-за состояния гонки при изменении глобальных переменных `int count, ItsMe;` из разных потоков.

Answer (score 1):

У вас перепутаны местами присвоения переменным.

```
ItsMe = omp_get_thread_num();
count = omp_get_num_threads();
```